# if one of them is empty username or password

Tags: javascript, jquery

if it is such that I have written user name but no password then it should come up with an error.

the problem is that it shows only if both inputs are empty and there is no content at all.

what I would like was if one of them is empty username or password

```
$(function () {
     var $login = $("#login"),
         $pwd = $("#pass"),
         $usr = $("#brugernavn");

     $login.on("submit", function (event) {
         var msg = "Husk ",
             usr = ($usr.val().trim() !== ""),
             pwd = ($pwd.val().trim() !== "");

         msg += !usr ? "brugernavn" : "";
         msg += !usr && !pwd ? " og " : "";
         msg += !pwd ? "kodeord" : "";

         (pwd && usr) || alert(msg);

         return (pwd && usr);
     });
 });
```

Comment: What's with all the crazy boolean short-hand? Allergic to `if`?

Comment: I'd take out the commas too.  Would make it more readible IMO.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the commas. It allows you to use the `var` keyword only once, instead of at the start of each variable declaration.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I'd rather see multiple var's on each line.  It's easier to see at a glance that three local vars are assigned.

Comment: It works correctly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8pV6B/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using the `&&` operator, which means and.

You want to use the `||` operator, which means or.

```
(pwd || usr) || alert(msg);
```

Comment: No, validation should only be successful if BOTH password and username are entered.

Comment: Wait, what? Changing to `||` means the alert will not be displayed if either variable is true.

Comment: Seriously, what am I missing? The code worked with `%%`. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvrL5/)